# How to get user info from firebase by adding it into a controller?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

How to get user info from firebase by adding it into a controller?

I wish to access user details such as email, name, age etc from a angular factory so I can show these details on the controller such as name, age, email etc..

What I have tried:

**Factory**

```
angular.module('...')
 .factory('UserDataService', function($q, $firebase, $firebaseAuth, FIREBASE_URL) {
var authData = {};

function authDataCallback(authData) {
  if (authData) {
    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + "/userProfiles/" + authData.uid);
    ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
      var data = snapshot.val();
      console.log(data.name); 
    });

  } else {
    console.log("User is logged out");
  }
}

// Register the callback to be fired every time auth state changes
var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
ref.onAuth(authDataCallback);

return {
    authData
};

});
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('....')
.controller('MainProfileController', function($scope, $firebaseArray, $ionicPopup, FIREBASE_URL, ProfilePics, UserDataService) {

$scope.auth = UserDataService;
console.log(UserDataService);


});
```

Comment: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/user-auth.html

Comment: How can I do this using a angular factory so that the name of the user can be shown on several controllers?

Comment: please show what you have tried. Question is too broad without code specifics

Comment: Updated my question with what I have tried. The issue is the asynchronous  callback. I wish to pass the users name and other credentials into an object which I can then access through several controllers